# WCF another best practice?

Tags: c#, wcf, service, failover

Ok so I have built my WCF service and its functioning great! However, I am starting to implement it into our pre-existing piece of software now and I am instantly running into the question, do I only use the proxy generated code and get rid of the dll that I used initially? Or do I keep both, and make distinctions between the two very obvious?

What I mean by keeping distinctions is, having a ServerUser and a LocalUser property that represent the same user object. However, my LocalUser property would be filled via the dll that the app initally ran with, if the application service is unavailable.

My main reasoning for this thought pattern is that if I remove my dll, I have a single point of failure. If for some reason my ServiceHost is just not up and running, but the DB server is, I would want my users to still be able to do their job. The features that the new WCF implementation utilize are not dependant for employees to do their job. It is more of a convenience in what the WCF service provides. Also, building in this kind of logic to the Service would allow service modifications more readily available in a non IIS hosted environment.

Also, is there a way to build in logic on the service so that when I pull down the proxy code for the client that it just knows to access the DB manually if the ServiceHost is unavailable? If this was a possibility, I think about 90% of all my problems would disappear.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think I need more info to make a good answer but I don't think that it's a good idea to have two path (directly to the DB and through the service) - only use the service and hide the DB-layer

Comment: You could always provide a manual proxy that you create that can do anything you want it to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you describe it sounds like keeping your existing DLL, i.e. direct access to the DB, would best suit your needs. Having a WCF service adds nothing if, when it fails, you'll just use the DLL anyway.

Ideally you would go with the WCF service completly and offer some kind of redundency to deal with any potenial service issues. Plus, using a service will mean you won't have to deal with any DLL upgrades/deployments.

But, from your question, it sounds like there would be some real issues to deal with should the service not be available, so just do with the DLL.

EDIT: Just read the last part of your question and I don't think that is possible. The proxy code for accessing services is generated when you add the reference to your project. The kind of "dynamic" information you're after would actually require a service.

EDIT: As a follow up to my comment below you could test this by creating a DLL and class, lets call it Class1. Then create a WCF service with a method that will return Class1. Create a client application and add a reference to the service. If you look at the proxy-generated code you should see (hopefully...I'm thinking of this as I type :)) that the method returns Class1, but when you compile it won't be able to find Class1. This is because Class1 does not have the DataContractAttribute which would auto-generate Class1 on the client. So, you have to distribute the shared DLL to the client. Now when the method returns and WCF tries to re-create Class1 it will use the local version in the shared DLL. Your other DLL, which will already be on the client, would use the same shared DLL.

Comment: Let me ask you this, is there an easy way for me to make it so that the client application can easily interpret the objects that come back from either the service or the dll? An example, AppNamespace.Data.MyMethod returns List<AppNamespace.Data.MyListObjects> however, the service returns back List<Appnamespace.Service.MyListObjects>. Even though they are the exact same object its confused because it is not within the same namespace.

Comment: It may be possible if you had a shared DLL with classes used by both the DLL and the service. If you had a service method that returned a class from the shared DLL, such as AClass MyMethod(), then the proxy code would look look exactly the same on the client-side because you would be returning an actual class, and not a Data Contract, i.e. the class would not be auto-generated, therefore the client-side would expect to find the class locally in the shared DLL. Your DLL would also use the same shared DLL. This way both the DLL and service would reference classes in the same, shared, location.

Comment: Ok yeah near the end of my day today I was able to get fairly close. I think my next step if it's going to be possible is to add my service reference to my data.dll so that all of my data ops are bundled into one package for client or server use. I am trying to make this as reusable as possible and easy enough for the next guy to come after me to be able to pickup. Thank you for your time. You all on stackoverflow are like my coworkers to bounce stuff off of cause here I have none.

Comment: Gave the server version the dll, started server. When I gave the client version the service reference it put it under its own namespace. ClientAppNamespace.ServiceReference1.Class1.GetClass returns a ClientAppNamespace.ServiceReference1.Class1 object. And I did not supply DataContract to the class in the dll. However, adding the service reference generated its own values for it. My assumption is VS is trying to be smart with Svcutil.

Comment: I will tell you what did work though. I was able to tell my client to reuse my DLL references for the types that the service reference would auto generate and that fixed my problems.

Comment: I did that by going to Add Service Reference, Advanced, Reuse types in specified referenced assemblies. That created a bunch of DataSources in my Properties folder which I dont like but hey it gets the job done.